# Taiwanese passport holder entering Croatia

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, croatia, taiwanese-citizens

I am a Taiwanese passport holder, I am going to Croatia in 2 days. I just want to confirm visa is not required for Taiwanese passport holder. Any reference from the Croatia official website I can find that mention the visa free policy?

Comment: Croatia has a [website](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) for checking whether you need a visa, but curiously Taiwan does not seem to appear in their drop-down list of countries.

Comment: @pnuts: Go to the bottom of the page; there is a world map graphic with a drop-down in the middle of it.

Comment: I just sent an email to the official site. Thank you for the quick response. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @pnuts: Of course, one has to wonder whether this is merely an oversight or a political decision, given that the People's Republic of China is very touchy about other countries recognizing Taiwan as an independent nation.  Though Croatia's [online visa application form](https://crovisa.mvep.hr/default.aspx?langId=en) does provide "TAIWAN, CHINA" as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official answer:

Dear Sir,

Referring to your email, please be informed that holders of HKSAR and Taiwan ordinary passports do not require a visa for Croatia. The exemption from the visa requirements applies to holders of ordinary passports issued by Taiwan which include an identity card number.

Passport has to be valid for at least another three months after the planned departure from Croatia and issued within the previous 10 years.

Best regards,

Division for Visas